# How to prevent the Trade of an ERC-721 if certain condition is met?

Tags: solidity

I have an ERC-721 token, and I want to implement a condition in the `transferFrom` function that prevents the token from being traded on the blockchain once a certain condition is met. Specifically, I want the token to have a limited lifespan of trading, let's say 5 trades, after which it should not be able to be listed on any kind of exchange.

However, I'm concerned that implementing this condition might make the ERC-721 token non-compliant with the standard followed by exchanges. I want to ensure that the token remains compatible with other exchanges while enforcing this trading limitation.

How can I implement this condition in a way that does not violate the ERC-721 standard and keeps the token available for trading on other exchanges?

Note: I am using Solidity and considering modifying the `transferFrom` function to enforce the trading limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you need to understand what ERC721, or for that matter, any interface standard is - it is simply a set of functions and events that the smart-contract needs to implement to be compliant.[image: IERC721 from OpenZeppelin]

The actual implementation is something that's left to the developer - for example, when `transferFrom` is called, usually this is handled by updating some internal `mapping(uint256 => address)` such that the `tokenId` points to a new wallet address. But there is no enforcement on this at all - if you decide to use an array with indexes instead, no one can stop you. You'll also see that the restriction that only the `tokenId` owner should be able to transfer it is not something that's defined on the interface level.  What I'm trying to say with all of this is, **an interface is just a promise**, an "external thing" third-party contracts (or marketplaces) can only check by calling `supportsInterface(interfaceId)`. Whether you actually fulfill the promise (or make a malicious contract), that's a whole different thing.

To get back to your original question, yes, you certainly can impose a transfer restriction (we already have NFTs with on-chain royalty enforcement).

For your scenario, you would have to override the internal `_transfer` function which is used in all three `(safe)transferFrom` variants and add a mapping to store how many times each token was transferred. Perhaps something like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract TransferRestrictedNFT is ERC721 {
    uint256 private immutable MAX_TOKEN_TRANSFERS;
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) private _tokenTransfers;

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 maxTokenTransfers
    ) ERC721(name, symbol) {
        MAX_TOKEN_TRANSFERS = maxTokenTransfers;
    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) internal virtual override {
        require(
            _tokenTransfers[tokenId] < MAX_TOKEN_TRANSFERS,
            "<YOUR ERROR MESSAGE>"
        );
        _tokenTransfers[tokenId]++;
        super._transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

I've given you a general example here, but you can probably modify it to only count "trades" if the operator is one of the major marketplaces.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your explanation clarified the issue, but it raised another question. If I add a maximum price for NFT trades, wouldn't that make the contract non-compliant with marketplaces? They don't use the price argument in the _transfer function's definition so they will discard the NFT collection. Unless they allow deploying my own exchange contract for my NFT collection, what can I do to ensure compliance to enforce the maximum price?

Comment: You can't add restrictions on the price as that's completely handled by the marketplace smart-contract.

Comment: Appreciate your help , thanks mate .